# Linking MYSQL (via PHP) on one EC2 instance to separate AWS EC2 instance

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to access an AWS EC2 instance located on the same subnet 17.31.x.x using a PHP call.

```
<?php

$dbHost = "http://172.31.x.x";
$dbUser = "<someuser>";
$dbDatabase = "<somedb>";
$dbPass = "<somepw>";

$ladb = new mysqli("$dbHost","$dbUser","$dbPass","$dbDatabase");

// Check connection
if ($ladb -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $ladb -> connect_error;
  exit();
}

?>
```

The Errno response is:

```
Failed to connect to MySQL: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

The Subnet is the same on both EC2 instances and the inbound and outbound access has been set to "everyone" on both to try and get this to work.

Still no luck. Happy with any direction / assistance.

Comment: I don't think you need http for host

Comment: Thanks @Marcin however I now get ``` connection refused ```

Comment: Can you check if DB port is Open? Try to telnet to DB port and see what happens...

Comment: @AshootoshBhardwaj I can telnet to the 3306 port - obviously closed by foreign host - however the port is open

Comment: Both. I managed to use the public IP to access (which wasn't ideal) as I wanted access to be within the subnet.